# Refreshing an Ember.View when the controller route changes

Tags: ember.js

I have a subclass of Ember.TextArea that displays some text from my model.

The View is rendered when the user goes to /:model_id

If the user is viewing /2, and then goes to /3, none of my lifecycle events are being called in the view.  didInsertElement isn't touched.  Only the value of the text area is changed with the new model.

What I really want to do is focus the text area every time the user goes to a /:model_id.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`didInsertElement` is only fired when it inserts the element into the page, not when you change models for a particular route, which just updates the template in page.

You can either observe the model on the controller and start some code when that happens, or hook into the `setupController` which is fired each time the model changes for a route.

Each time you'll want to be wary of not making changes until after it's rendered the changes into the page.  Using scheduling is generally the favorite route

```
Em.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', function(){
  alert('foo');
});
```